# Using Ansible, what is preferable way to check the presence of particular command in user's PATH?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Let say you want to determine whether the user 'abc' has the command 'command_abc' in user's PATH. What's the best way to do that kind of check?

Is there anything better than to just use **shell** module and execute something like

`sudo su abc which command_abc && echo 'ok'`

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

The only direct way I'm aware of is yours. But I would use **become_user** statements and the **command** module.

Hope that helps.

[old answer, but not the point of your question]

I would check if the path to the binary is set for him in **.bashrc** or **.profile** with **lineinfile**. After that a check for the right permissions on the binary should be enough, probably with the **stat** or **file module**. That way you have tested it too, but without the need of shell scripts.

Comment: Hello @Hoall, thank you for your opinion. It seems  **command** module is not suitable for executing _which_ command because $PATH variable is not available, it seems we have to use **shell** module..